# How can I create the same body multiple times in Box2D?

Tags: android, object, libgdx, box2d

The code below is a single asteroid that moves from right to left across the screen. What i want is to create an infinite amount of these that would be created after a time interval. How do I do this?

```
//ASTEROID

    ballD.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;

    //random location for asteroid
    int aLoc = (int) (aLocation * 15);
    float x = 260;
    switch(aLoc)
    {
    case 0:
        ballD.position.set(x, -110);
        break;
    case 1:
        ballD.position.set(x, -95);
        break;
    case 2:
        ballD.position.set(x, -80);
        break;
    case 3:
        ballD.position.set(x, -65);
        break;
    case 4:
        ballD.position.set(x, -50);
        break;
    case 5:
        ballD.position.set(x, -35);
        break;
    case 6:
        ballD.position.set(x, -20);
        break;
    case 7:
        ballD.position.set(x, -5);
        break;
    case 8:
        ballD.position.set(x, 10);
        break;
    case 9:
        ballD.position.set(x, 25);
        break;
    case 10:
        ballD.position.set(x, 40);
        break;
    case 11:
        ballD.position.set(x, 55);
        break;
    case 12:
        ballD.position.set(x, 70);
        break;
    case 13:
        ballD.position.set(x, 85);
        break;
    default:
        ballD.position.set(x, 0);
    }

    PolygonShape asteroid = new PolygonShape();
    asteroid.setAsBox(10f, 10);

    //asteroid definition
    fDef.shape = asteroid;
    fDef.density = .5f;
    fDef.friction = .25f;
    fDef.restitution = .75f;

    a = world.createBody(ballD);
    a.createFixture(fDef);

   //asteroid image
    aSprite = new Sprite(new Texture("img/asteroid-icon.png"));
    aSprite.setSize(10f * 4, 10f * 4);
    aSprite.setOrigin(aSprite.getWidth() / 2, aSprite.getHeight() / 2);
    a.setUserData(aSprite);

    asteroid.dispose();
```

Comment: Please don't repost your questions in case you didn't get an answer the first time. Try to reformulate your question, because for me it is unclear what exactly you try to do and what your problem is.

Comment: I tried making my description more clear. Hope it makes a little more sense now

Comment: you only need to set the position of the body multiple times(provided either its not currently in the scene or the asteroid is destroyed by something).